# Python Webbrowser hosts file

Tags: python, firefox, registry, browser, hosts

Well by using [WebBrowser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) i want to open for example the firefox browser
and point him to a simple address like example.com ! The following code is 
enough for that job !

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://www.example.com/'
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

But i want my webbrowser script to open a custom hosts file
not the one located here : c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
So is it possible to change that location using a python function 
or a arg through firefox.exe ?

Edit : Can we maybe be able to achieve it through the windows registry ?

```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
   %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc
```

if i change it to some other folder would that work ?

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with the web browser, thats handled by the networking stack AFAIK.

Comment: I think once you start the browser, it's relying on the OS to do name resolution. You'd have to reconfigure the OS (even temporarily). Why would you want to use a phony name in the URL?

Comment: Can we achieve that by editing the regedit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webbrowser module looks very minimalistic, I don't think is is possible.

But you could use HTTP proxy like squid, to which you can give different hostsfile.